# Embedded Jetty Instrumentation

Tags: spring, jetty, embedded-jetty, instrumentation

We are running our Spring application using an Embedded Jetty Server. We are in the need of instrumenting the Jetty Server. We checked this [link](https://dropwizard.github.io/metrics/3.1.0/manual/jetty/), but unable to find a working prototype of the same. Please suggest a way to instrument the Embedded Jetty.

Comment: Why use these classes? Why not use the built-in JMX provided information from core Jetty instead? (the standard Jetty JMX layers provide the same information that these special Dropwizard Instrumented classes provide)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Sure. Trying the same with the help of [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/JMX).

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt We are planning to use JMXTrans for pulling the data from the Jetty JMX. Since it is a pull model. How to determine the optimal interval time(Without affecting the performance) to poll the data. Will there be any performance hit?